# How can a userdefined context menu item from my VisualStudio Addin be realized

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-addins

How can a userdefined context menu item from my VisualStudio Addin be realized.
I need it in an TXAEShell VStudio Automation Environment from Beckhoff to initialize a Ethercat bus scan  and reading action of highlited items ..!

I know how to read the PLC Items as Programs and functions -
the challenge is to catch a rightclick in the items explorer and enhance the builtin contextmenu with the Addin feature.

I went through MSDN Articles and found stuff close to it but not the full hit - with Itemnames from the VS ObjectModels or bookable events...

A deep trick... deep inside VisualStudio..
Are there any uggestions or even a ready to use code piece for that?

Best Regards Tilman